# Exception Handling in Protractor

Tags: protractor

How can we catch unhanded exceptions at the application level? I want to log the unhanded exceptions in a log file.

Comment: Do you want to catch application level exceptions or Protractor level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add second callback to `.then()`:

[Via Protractor FAQ:](http://www.protractortest.org/#/faq#how-can-i-catch-errors-such-as-elementnotfound-)

```
elm.click().then(function() { /* passing case */}, function(err) { /* error handling here */})
```

Or, if you are using `async/await`, you can handle it in regular `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    await elm.click();
    /* passing case */
} catch (err) {
    /* error handling here */
}
```